# RAID with pen-drives, it is possible?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, raid-1, usb-flash-drive

Can Windows 7 manage 2 or more pen-drives (or external disk drives) to implement a RAID-1 to backup the content of them? I have a pen-drive and an external hard disk, both with really relevant and important information, however, as I know both of them can be unsecure (I mean, I need to backup the content of one in the other). What I was wondering is if can I automate the process of creating backups on my drivers by just creating a RAID-1 on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAID-1 isn't a backup, it's a mirror. It doesn't help you if you've deleted something that you want to recover because it's deleted from both volumes.  I'm certain that this isn't possible because the system cannot guarantee that you'll insert both of the USB drives at the same time.

Another option would be to include a copy of robocopy.exe on the flash drive along with a batch file that when run will copy all modified files to the other drive. You can then just make sure you run the batch file whenever you plug in the two drives (assuming the drive letters stay the same).